# Starting all my servers each in their own tab using bash

Tags: python, linux, bash, gnome-terminal

I have a few servers I'm trying to run by executing a single bash script. I don't know bash at all this is my first attempt at a script but through a bit of Googling I hacked this together and it worked:

```
#!/bin/bash

gnome-terminal \
    --tab -e \
        'sh -c "cd /path1 && ./server1; exec bash"' \
    --tab -e \
        'sh -c "cd /path2 && ./server2; exec bash"' \
    --tab -e \
        'sh -c "cd /path3 && ./server3; exec bash"' \
    --tab -e \
        'sh -c "cd /path4 && java -jar javaserver; exec bash"'
```

Now I'm running the first python server in a virtualenv so I wanted to be able to give a command line argument to decide which virtualenv to load (or use default), so I've been trying something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]
  then
    virtualenv="default"
  else
    virtualenv=$1
fi

gnome-terminal \
    --tab -e \
        'sh -c "cd /path1 && source ../$virtualenv/bin/activate && ./server1; exec bash"' \
    --tab -e \
        'sh -c "cd /path2 && ./server2; exec bash"' \
    --tab -e \
        'sh -c "cd /path3 && ./server3; exec bash"' \
    --tab -e \
        'sh -c "cd /path4 && java -jar javaserver; exec bash"'
```

Because I'm doing `sh -c` I think I'm running these commands using sh instead of bash inside my bash script (`bash -c` wasn't working) so "source" is unknown, also it doesn't understand the variable `$virtualenv` likely for the same reason.

Apparently you can push over arguments using `$@` which I had trouble doing, but either way I think I'm doing this all wrong in the first place. I don't really need to cd to the paths either not sure why I'm doing that, could simplify the script.

I'd appreciate a hand from someone who actually knows bash in the proper way of doing this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This script allows one to open a tab in the same working directory.(I have an alias for this script so that I type the alias to open a new tab.) .....But see, you can call in variables and perform actions. Thus, you can implement your commands using this as a basis. This script is for unix/mac but I figured it could still be helpful.

```
#!/bin/sh

pwd=`pwd`
osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\"" \
    -e "tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"t\" using {command down}" \
    -e "do script \"cd $pwd; clear\" in front window" \
    -e "end tell"
    > /dev/null
```

Comment: That is AppleScript apparently, so not usable for me, but I can see if there is a similar method to this. Possibly a bash alternative to the `tell` command that passes through variables.